# only one popup displayed on the openlayers

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, popup, jquery

The issue is that i only one popup on the map is dispalyed. I can see all the points but popup can see only on the last point of the list. Please check my code http://jsfiddle.net/3HSjY/24/ I'm stack with rhis problem from Sunday and can not find any info that could solve my problem on the internet :(

Comment: Post you code here

Comment: this is my code [link](http://jsfiddle.net/3HSjY/24/), but i just find out that when i open it in IE i can see all points and popups, but in Chrome i can only see all points and only one popup

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is, that you defined the popup and the selectcontrol, etc in a loop.
I would put everything out of the loop beginning with this line:

```
map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
```